# flutter app with keycloak and openid_client Unauthorized error

Tags: flutter

I use the openid_client library in flutter mobile app with keycloak server. But when I use access token ,i obtain 401 Unauthorized error.

This my Flutter code

```html
login async(){


var uri = Uri.parse(env["KEYCLOAKURL"].toString());
 var clientId = env["KEYCLOAKCLIENTID"].toString();
 var scopes = List<String>.of(['openid', 'profile', 'offline_access']);
 var issuer = await Issuer.discover(uri);
 var client = new Client(issuer, clientId);
 urlLauncher(String url) async {
   if (await canLaunch(url)) {
          await launch(url);
          } else {
               throw 'Could not launch $url';
             }
   }
var authenticator = new Authenticator(client,
    scopes: scopes, port: 8080, urlLancher: urlLauncher);

var c = await authenticator.authorize();

TokenResponse tokenResponse = await c.getTokenResponse();
await this.storage.write(key: "REFRESH", value: tokenResponse.refreshToken);
await this.storage.write(key: "TOKEN", value: tokenResponse.accessToken);

closeWebView();
}
```

My keycloak configuration :

```html
{
  "realm": "Lmaydane",
  "auth-server-url": "http://localhost:8080/auth/",
  "ssl-required": "none",
  "resource": "flutter",
  "public-client": true,
  "verify-token-audience": true,
  "use-resource-role-mappings": true,
  "confidential-port": 0
}
```

Can someone help me?